# How to deploy a Qt application on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, deployment

So now I can make a .exe of my application. Now how do I get my application ready to deploy for windows?

This is meant to be the canonical question for Qt application deployment issues on Windows.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Qt documentation has pages for that:

- [Qt 5](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html),
- [Qt 4](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/deployment-windows.html).