# creating setup.exe in C++, QT

Tags: c++, qt, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to deploy a Qt application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622418/how-to-deploy-a-qt-application)

I can make some QT or C++ programs. But these are suitable for my computer. I want to create a setup file, so I can install them to other computers which don't have C++

Is there any easy way to do this??

Answer (score 1):

I think Visual Studio is able to create setup.exe files which contain all needed files to run your application.

But I can also highly recommend [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page), an easy to learn script language which allows you to create your own customized setups where you can put in and execute all files necessary for your application.

It's important that you include the appropriate Visual C++ Redistributable Package (depending on which compiler your application was built with).

Comment: Duplicate question, but +1 for mentioning NSIS in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Qt with CMake, [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) could be a really good solution.