# Finish building the Qt project

Tags: qt

I've finished my program and I want to know how can I close the project, or every time I want to use it on a different computer I have to have Qt creator installed?

Comment: What do you mean? You've built your exe? Or have you just been playing around in the designer and there is no functionality to your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to run your program in another computer and without Qt creator ! you must deploy your project. It means that you should compile it and prepare its necessities.
Maybe [here is a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622418/how-to-deploy-a-qt-application) that can help you!