# Qt based app 'Qt platform plugin windows not found' issue when opening a file

Tags: c++, windows, qt, platform

Probably most of the people that has experience with `Qt5` libraries will say that I should copy `qwindows.dll` to `myappfolder/platforms/qwindows.dll`.

That was already made and working flawlessly.

The problem is that I've registered the extension of my files with that app and when I double click to open a file the app crashes since it cannot find that `qwindows.dll`.

Desesperatly also I tried without luck this code:

```
QApplication::addLibraryPath(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath());
QDir::setCurrent(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath());
QApplication::addLibraryPath("./");
QString sDir = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath();
QApplication::addLibraryPath(sDir);
QApplication::addLibraryPath(sDir+"/plugins/");
QApplication::addLibraryPath(sDir+"/platforms/");
```

But I had no luck neither.

Any tip?

As I wrote in the comments this is not the same a the deploy issue since the .exe opens fine if it gets open directly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deploy a Qt application on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/622418/how-to-deploy-a-qt-application-on-windows)

Comment: No, as I said I can deploy it without problems I mean it opens fine if I try to open the .exe directly, the problem only happens if I associate an extension and open that file, so it could be something similar to open it using a command line.

Comment: Try to discriminate between a wrong searchpath or a plugin problem. If only qwindows.dll is a problem you might need to add a qt.conf file

Answer (score 0):

So I am guessing that by running it like this actually sets the application default directory where the shortcut is.
You could test it by putting your shortcut/whatever file in the same directory as your .exe and see if that works.

There are ways to tell Qt loader to look elsewhere but I have never actually played with it. Look here:http://www.tripleboot.org/?p=536
And search for QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH
I think it's on about setting a system variable to your .exe location
set QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=c:\myapp

Good luck