# Qt platform plugin "windows" is not found on one computer

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I have an application built with Qt 5.5, deployed and running on x86 Windows 7 with dynamic linking. When I try to launch it *on that particular computer*, I get the following error:

> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the
>   Qt platform plugin "windows".
>
> Available platform plugins are: minimal, offscreen, windows, windows.
>
> Reinstalling the application may fix the problem.

The "windows" plugin is indeed repeated twice in the list.

Though I have the libraries set up properly, such that they run without an issue on my main computer, here, the `platforms` directory doesn't seem to be found.

File list:

```
MyProject\platforms\qwindows.dll
MyProject\Qt5Core.dll
MyProject\Qt5Cored.dll
MyProject\Qt5Gui.dll
MyProject\Qt5Guid.dll
MyProject\Qt5Widgets.dll
MyProject\Qt5Widgetsd.dll
MyProject\MyProject.exe
```

Many similar questions can be found about this error, but I have tried all the answers I have found about it (including changing file and folder names, adding various extra Qt libraries to the directory, etc.) without success. I have built the application again while making sure that all components have the right architecture, again without success.

*Other than static linking, how can I make it run?*

Comment: Try to use windeployqt to autocollect libraries

Comment: Burich: thank you, it worked; I am not sure which library was missing, but I feel silly for not thinking of using it before. If you will submit an answer with the details, I will approve it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deploy a Qt application on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/622418/how-to-deploy-a-qt-application-on-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use windeployqt.
It'll try to autocollect all needed libraries.

Comment: `windeployqt <release_dir>\MyProject.exe` fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the folder '**platforms**' from the \$QTDIR\$version\$complier\**plugins**\ (which must contains the files *qwindows.dll* and *qminimal.dll*) near your .exe file.

Usual list of dlls for Qt 5 on Windows:

[image]

Comment: He has the "qwindows.dll" in the "platforms" folder which should be correct, or what do mean with "near your .exe file"? For what would you need the "qminimal.dll" ?

Comment: Folder **platforms** must be near your .exe file

Comment: Does your app folder contain all icuxx.dll ?. Does your **platforms** folder contain *qminimal.dll* ?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH` environment variable [worked for me](https://github.com/pyqt/python-qt5/issues/2).

This solution was also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37918282/109941) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29563968/109941).

Answer (score 0):

Open Cmd and write this for qtquick deployment (remove `--qmldir` for non qtquick):

```
 windeployqt --qmldir <path-to-app-qml-files> <path-to-app-binary>
```

For example:

```
windeployqt --qmldir C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Dyn
amicView C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\build-DynamicView-vc-Release\release
```

Write `windeployqt` for more details.