# qt release application files

Tags: qt, dll, exe

I wrote and compiled a program in QT, but I wanted to be able to send the .exe file to run on another computer. However, some .dll files are needed to ship with the application.

What are the locations of these dll files?

Comment: Have answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35068344/how-to-compile-a-standalone-with-qt-creator-on-windows/35069261#35069261

Answer (score 1):

Inthe docs, there's a chapter about it:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html

at the very end it mentions the `windeployqt` command

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the Qt *.dll files, they are located in the *bin* folder, inside your Qt installation directory.