# Can't find right Qt5Core.dll file. Each one I find gives a different error

Tags: c++, qt, dll, deployment, version

I'm trying to deploy my Qt application, and every I tried loading Qt5core.dll, and it gave me an error, saying something like "procedure entry point.... could not be found".

So I tried loading a different version that was on my machine, and all of them gave me a slightly different but similar error.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deploy a Qt application on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/622418/how-to-deploy-a-qt-application-on-windows)

Comment: Check that you are compiling in Release mode.

Comment: I am.  Actually, when I compile in debug and use the debug version of the dll's, everything works fine.  It is the release .dll's that give me the problem

Comment: I tried using the deployment instructions posted by MrEric Sir, but none of it works.  When I type "configure" in my command prompt, no matter what directory i type it from, it gives me a "no file or command" type error.

Answer (score 0):

By the look of your question, I suspect you want to deploy your project on Windows as you have struggle to find the correct .dll files.

I usually use the Windows deployement tool from Qt (more info on their website here: [windeployqt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html#the-windows-deployment-tool), it is located within the `QTDIR/bin/` folder.

But it is very straightforward to use, I use it as follow:

```
windeployqt --release "C:\path\to\binary.exe"
```

You should then be able to deploy your app by copying the resulting output files from the previous command.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I tried doing exactly that.   Where you typed "c:\path\to\binary.exe"  I typed the location of the executable that was created with qt.  It then told me that it couldn't find the file specified.  I tried with and without quotes;; both didnt work.

Comment: the exact error is:

Unable to query qmake: CreateProcessW failed: The system cannot find the file sp
ecified.

Comment: Try to drag and drop the compiled file onto the terminal after you've type:
"windeployqt --release"  
That should add you the file and its path with quotes and everything.

Comment: ok I found out I needed to copy qmake into the directory (or set the path) and now it seems like its working, then it craps out at this point:

Creating qt_ca.qm...
CreateProcessW failed: The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: I start to thing that you didn't correctly install Qt (or setup the environment properly). It's failing when trying to create the translation/qml file. Which means the windeployqt tool can't find the Qt directory nor Qt binaries.

Can you please provide us with a screenshot of the terminal after you've tried the command please?

Answer (score 0):

Got it!  I was including Qt5Network.dll when I was trying something out, but forgot I no longer needed it.  It was calling a procedure in Qt5Core.dll that wasn't in the version I was using.